# NASM: in/out instead of int

Tags: assembly, nasm

When writing a bootloader how do you make calls to ports instead the use of interrupts (i.e. `int 10h`)? Is there a list someplace online I am unaware of for known vectors? Is there a place I can go to do mapping of hardware not covered by the bios interrupts (i.e. PCI - GPUs)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the problem is that it is not just the *mapping of hardware*, as well as it is not just the bootloader in the computer.

What you are really talking about is the writing of a driver. BIOS manages the simplest devices and uses the best available methods to achieve what a programmer wants. And for the programmer there is that API to access it, which for the x86 real mode means interrupts, as they are the simplest way of doing a complete context switch.

If you still want to remain in real mode, there are several more interrupts you probably are not aware of, that can be found in somehow complete [Ralf Brown´s Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm).

However, PCI and GPUs works on high frequencies with *lots* of data, and that requires much more memory and performance, which can not be easily operated on with real mode. Protected and Long mode are the way to go.

I8086 has mentioned `in` and `out` instructions as the method of accessing devices.
Whilst this used to be true and for some devices keeps true, there are many other ways of communicating with hardware, e.g. memory mapping, DMA or communication with coprocessors. Sometimes you just use `in` and `out` to find out where device´s memory lies to access it using a memory-mapped interface. I believe PCI is one of them. These interfaces are not any more difficult to work with, but they are more effective.

You will almost immediately hit the wall called "lack of official and free documentation". You must not get disappointed by this, there is always plenty of devices that have their datasheets and programmer references freely available (let's admit that Intel has a massive documentation), although it isn't always going to be your own GPU or network card.

TL;DR: You should switch to the protected mode as soon as possible to unlock a new range of options, and then you can think of writing some drivers. [OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) is surely going to be a great resource.

Answer (score 4):

You can communicate with I/O ports via the `in` & `out` instructions.

`in dest, src`: Where `dest` is the input; I'm pretty sure only the accumulator register can be used as the `dest`. The `src` is the port number. `src` can be the data register or an immediate value.

`out dest, src`: Where `dest` is the port number; this time the data register or an immediate value is used for the `dest`. The `src` is the output. `src` can be the accumulator register.

Given the lack of information, I'm assuming your boot loader is for the x86 and that you'll be limited more or less to 512 bytes of space. If that's the case, I would recommend using the interrupts provide for you by the BIOS until you load the kernel.

More information can be found on [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Other_Instructions), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Original_8086.2F8088_instructions), and the [OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/I/O_Ports).